# points lost even though answer is accepted

Tags: support

[image]

I should have 10 points more since answer is accepted

Answer (score 3):

You did get 25 reputation from that answer, see your [reputation page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/197451/js-bibra?tab=reputation):

[image]

I'm not sure why the upvote doesn't appear on your [reputation summary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/197451/js-bibra?tab=summary).

Comment: I will get :-) some points to the user for the peaceful :-). My best regards.